# Custom Link In Wordpress Media "Attachment Details" Upload Screen

Tags: customization, uploads, media, links

When you click "Add Media" and from there select an image from that media library screen on the right you get a breakdown (the attachment details) related to that particular image.

Right below the image there are some image details and then the links > Edit Image > Delete Permanently.

How can I add a custom link to appear right there (preferably) above the "Edit Image" link with a function?

I searched around and the closest I could find it how to add custom fields to the media upload screen nearest to the bottom options in the right when an image is selected. I couldn't find and I'm not sure how to take that snippet and take the field area to be just a link instead.

I used in my description above "image" just for visual purposes. I want the link to appear for all files from the media upload screen, not just images if someone is thinking that.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hacky way to do it is to do a string replace on the `tmpl-attachment-details` template:

```
// See wp_print_media_templates() in "wp-includes/media-template.php"
function wpse157297_print_media_templates() {
    $my_link = '<a class="my_link-attachment" href="my_link.php?url={{ data.url }}" target="_blank">' . __( 'My Link' ) . '</a>';
    $nonimage = '<# if ( "image" !== data.type && ! data.uploading ) { #>' . $my_link . '<# } #>';
    $image = $my_link;
?>
<script>
(function ($) {
    var tmpl_attachment_details = $('#tmpl-attachment-details'), html = tmpl_attachment_details.html();
    tmpl_attachment_details.html(
        html.replace( /<div class="uploaded">[^<]*<\/div>/, '$&<?php echo $nonimage; ?>' ).replace( '<a class="edit-attachment"', '<?php echo $image; ?>$&' )
    );
})(jQuery);
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'print_media_templates', 'wpse157297_print_media_templates', 11 );
```

Apart from `{{ data.url }}`, there's `{{ data.id }}`, `{{ data.filename }}` etc - see `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js()` in "wp-includes/media.php"

Comment: Very awesome @bonger. Thanks! Works perfectly. I had to make one adjust which was to take out the "?url={{ data.url }}" for my url. So this link just opens a backend page the site. I really appreciate it.